# I can't connect the react-native in my cellphone

Tags: react-native, usb, native

I already connected my cell phone to the USB cable and checked the prompt that the device was showing,
but when I use the npm start command and choose the android one it gives this error:
info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Nativjsestudar'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No matching variant of project :gradle-plugin was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime,
> compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version'
> with value '8.0.1' but:
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a library, packaged as
> a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'mainSourceElements' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified declares a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)
> uring runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component,
> compatible with Java 8
> - Other compatible attribute:
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Variant 'testResultsElementsForTest' capability com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:unspecified:
> - Incompatible because this component declares a component of category 'verification' and the consumer needed a library
> - Other compatible attributes:
> - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
> - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
> - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0.1')
> - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required runtime)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I'm new in react and i'm trying to do this if you can help me some how, i will be glad thanks

I just want connect to my device

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't enable the USB debugging mode in your mobile, go to developer option in settings and enable it.

Comment: I have already did it

Comment: still didn't work then?

Comment: hey sorry i didn't anwser, no it didn't' I think is because my CPU that is a ryzen but I'm not sure

Comment: have you been stuck on this issue for the last 2 months? :o 
Let me know if you need any guidance or help from me. happy to help you out!